# ReactJS: replacing object from array with new value replaces whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have array `selectedItems` and when I try to update existing object:

```
i.e. [{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 1}]
```

to:

```
i.e. [{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 3}]
```

It replaces the whole array with:

```
 [ { lable: "two", uniqueId: 3 }]
```

how can I avoid that?

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
  const { selectedItems } = this.state
  const findExistingItem = selectedItems.find((item) => {
    return item.uniqueId === uniqueId;
  })

  if(findExistingItem) {
    selectedItems.splice(findExistingItem);
    this.setState(state => ({
      selectedItems: [...state.selectedItems, {
        label, uniqueId
      }]
    }))
  } else {
    this.setState(state => ({
      selectedItems: [...state.selectedItems, {
        label, uniqueId
      }]
    }))
  }
}
```

Comment: `find` returns the item ... so, what do you think `selectedItems.splice(findExistingItem)` does? hint: nothing - you'll want `const findExistingItem = selectedItems.findIndex(.....` and `if(findExistingItem >= 0)` ...or `if(~findExistingItem)`

Comment: @JaromandaX right. I got to point where I found uniqueId but having trouble replacing with new one. I tried `splice` and `slice`. what should I use instead of splice

Comment: actually, that won't do either, since "uniqueId" is the same so there can be more than one ... odd choice of property name since it isn't unique

Comment: @JaromandaX yea I should probably change that to something more appropriate. thanks for pointing out

Comment: how are you calling `handleChange`? what do the arguments mean?

Comment: in words, what is the logic for how `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 1}]` would become `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 3}]` ?

Comment: `Array.find()` returns the reference of the found object, and that object can be modified directly. Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57950903/2924577

Comment: @JaromandaX this data is coming from group of radio buttons

Comment: yeah but that doesn't actually answer the question I asked

Comment: @JaromandaX so consider `label` as `Select your age` and have 3 radio button options `0-30 , 31-60, 61-100` which have ids (uniqueId) `1, 2, 3`. user selected first option (added to array) and changed it later to option second. thats where I was having issue. hope that answer's your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the `Array#filter` and `Array#concat` functions in tandem, where;

- items that don't match on `uniqueId` are filtered. This substitutes the `find()` logic of your current solution followed by,
- the `concat()` method being called to append the new "replacement item" to the end of the filtered array

In code that could be achieved like this:

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
  const {
    selectedItems
  } = this.state

  this.setState({
    selectedItems : selectedItems
      /* Filter any existing item matching on uniqueId */
      .filter(item => (item.uniqueId !== uniqueId))
      /* Append replacement { label, uniqueId } to state array */
      .concat([ { label, uniqueId } ])
  });
}
```

Comment: what combination of arguments to  `handleChange`  will change `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 1}]` to `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 3}]` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) finds the element in the array and returns its reference.

You can modify the returned object, and then update the state.

> Also, you can change the `find()` condition to find the item by
>   `label` or `uniqueId` based on your needs. To get the output in your
>   question, you have to find by `label` not `uniqueId`.

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
  const { selectedItems } = this.state;

  const findExistingItem = selectedItems.find((item) => {
    // To find by 'label', replace 'uniqueId' below with 'label'.
    return item.uniqueId === uniqueId;
  })

  if(findExistingItem) {
    // You are not passing in 'newUniqueId', so only 'label' is updated.
    findExistingItem.label = label;
    findExistingItem.uniqueId = uniqueId;
  } 

  this.setState(state => ({
    selectedItems: selectedItems
  }));
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function handleChange(label, uniqueId) {

  const selectedItems = [{label: "one",uniqueId: 1}, {label: "two", uniqueId: 1 }];

  const findExistingItem = selectedItems.find(item => { 
     // Finding by 'label', change to 'uniqueId' if that is what is needed.
     return item.label === label;
  });

  if(findExistingItem) {
    findExistingItem.label = label;
    findExistingItem.uniqueId = uniqueId;
  } 
 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedItems));
}

handleChange("two", 3);
```

Comment: what combination of arguments to  `handleChange`  will change `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 1}]` to `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 3}]` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX - `handleChange("two", 1)` will change the label of an object but `uniqueId` won't be changed, as we are using the same `uniqueId` to find the element in first place. OP isn't passing `newUniqueId`. You should ask OP about this, but why downvote every answer on the page?

Comment: because y'all didn't produce the expected output - therefore "this answer is not useful" ... none produce the required result

Comment: The required result is fixing the error OP had, not changing his input. I saw your answer and you assumed `label` is the filtering criteria, how can you assume that when OP themselves has used `uniqueId` in the question itself?

Comment: erm ... look at question ... what the data is, and what result is desired ... now, use your code to achieve the desired result

Comment: @JaromandaX - Also works in mine. Remove downvote as I also addressed that issue now.

Answer (score -1):

If you omit the second argument of `.splice` (the number of elements to remove), it removes all elements from the index on:

```
  const arr = [1, 2, 3];
  arr.splice(0);
  console.log(arr);
```

You might want to only splice `1`, and you might want to start at the elements index, not it's value.

Comment: so, what does `arr.splice({lable: "two", uniqueId: 1});` do?

Comment: which would probably be unexpected by the OP :p

Answer (score -1):

I think the question is misleading

I think what the OP wants to do is find the label passed in to the function and change the uniqueId of the matching array entry - given the result being `[{lable: "two", uniqueId: 3}]` would mean that handleChange is being called

```
handleChange('two', 3);
```

Given that the logic is more like the following

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        selectedItems: state.selectedItems.map(item => Object.assign(item, item.lable === label ? {uniqueId} : {}))
    });
}
```

to illustrate this works:

```js
const handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
    const selectedItems = [{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 1}];
    return selectedItems.map(item => Object.assign(item, item.lable === label ? {uniqueId} : {}))
};

console.log(handleChange('two', 3));
```

---

or to "borrow" some nicer code, and FIX it

```
handleChange = (lable, uniqueId) => {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state
    const selectedItem = selectedItems.filter(item => item.lable !== lable)
    this.setState({  selectedItems:  [...selectedItem, { lable, uniqueId }] })
}
```

Demonstrate it works and produces expected result:

```js
const handleChange = (lable, uniqueId) => {
    const selectedItems = [{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 1}];
    const selectedItem = selectedItems.filter(item => item.lable !== lable)
    return({  selectedItems:  [...selectedItem, { lable, uniqueId }] })
};

console.log(handleChange('two', 3));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter and setState

```
handleChange = (label, uniqueId) => {
  const { selectedItems } = this.state
  // filter data if exists other wise return present array
  const selectedItem = selectedItems.filter(item => item.uniqueId !== uniqueId)

  this.setState({  selectedItems:  [...selectedItem, { label, uniqueId }] })
}
```

Filter slice based on uniqueId an append new if not exists

Comment: basically the same code as the accepted answer refactored ... so, let me ask you, what combination of arguments to  `handleChange`  will change `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 1}]` to `[{lable: "one", uniqueId: 1}, {lable: "two", uniqueId: 3}]` ?